# How to bind a class on click event of elements obtained through a loop?

Tags: javascript, css, class, vue.js

I go through an array of objects to display in my html some information boxes that are selectable. For it I bind a class in the event click, but as I obtain the elements through a v-for, when I select one it bind the class to all of them.

How can I differentiate only the selected one?

I have seen several examples with jquery but I would like to know if there is any other method.

My template:

```html
<div class="list-services">
  <div class='column-service' 
    v-for='estimation in filteredEstimation' 
    v-bind:key="estimation.name" 
    :class="{ focusService }" 
    @click="focusService = !focusService"
  >
    <div class="service-name">
      {{estimation.name}}
    </div>
    <div class="service-description">
      {{estimation.description}}
    </div>
    <div class="service-price">
      {{estimation.price}} 
      <span class="price-currency">€</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to make a jsfiddle to answer your question, but then I found this jsfiddle on the vue.js forum: https://jsfiddle.net/mogtfpze/2/

It offers three different options for highlighting content by clicking.

```
li v-for="item in items" 
  :class="{highlight:item.id == selected}" 
  @click="selected = item.id">
  {{item.id}}
</li>
```

Although it's an old answer, I believe it should still be compatible with the current Vue version.

If not, or if something is not clear, just let me know and I'll try to help you out!

Comment: thank you so much!!
works perfect! the first option would be the desired behavior, but I have tried all 3 and they work without problem!

Answer (score 2):

The method that I use personally (If I understand your question correctly) is the `this` keyword.

For example:

index.html

```html
<ul id="myList">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

script.js (Vanilla JavaScript)

```js
var myList = document.getElementById("myList");
    myList.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.innerText);
});
```

script.js (jQuery)

```js
var myList = $("#myList").on("click", function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.innerText);
});
```

In this case, using the `this` keyword allows us to get the innerText of the `li` element that was clicked by only attaching the event listener to the parent element. `innerHtml` is only one of many ways to use this keyword. You can see more of them by doing `console.log(this)` in your event listener function.

Let me know if this helps!